# Mutable ref becomes immutable inside closure

Tags: rust

I have this function to generate a random vector.

```
pub fn random_vec(r: &mut rng::Rng, n: u32) -> Vec<Flo> {
    (0..n).map(|_| r.next_normal()).collect()
}
```

I use it to generate a vector of 3 random vectors like this.

```
let xs: Vec<Vec<Flo>> =
    (0..3).map(|_| random_vec(&mut r, n)).collect();
```

This works fine. Now I try to extract this line into a function.

```
fn random_vecs(r: &mut rng::Rng, n: u32) -> Vec<Vec<Flo>> {
    (0..3).map(|_| random_vec(&mut r, n)).collect()
}
```

This fails with message: "closure cannot assign to immutable argument `r`". Why does Rust want `r` to be immutable?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. For example, we don't know what `rng` or `Flo`  are. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: Please read the *complete* error message. And then follow its suggestion and remove the `&mut` inside the function.

Comment: Thanks, following the compiler suggestion and removing the `&mut` works. Unfortunately, VSCode displays only the beginning of the message; I had to use the CLI to read the (excellent) hint!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, because the formal argument `r` of `random_vecs` is not mutable, and by the `&mut r` in the body you are trying to construct a mutable reference to it.

Here is a simplified example with the essentials of what you are doing:

```
fn modify0(r: &mut usize) {
    *r += 1;
}

fn modify1(r: &mut usize) {
    modify0(&mut r);
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = 1;
    modify1(&mut a);

    println!("Hello, {:?}!", a);
}
```

The error message is

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable argument `r` as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:6:18
  |
6 |     modify0(&mut r);
  |                  ^ cannot borrow mutably
help: consider removing the `&mut`, as it is an immutable binding to a mutable reference
```

To fix it, you could make it mutable (don't, it's not a good idea, even though it works here):

```
fn modify1(mut r: &mut usize) {
    modify0(&mut r);
}
```

Better is to follow the suggestion in the error message and remove the superfluous `&mut`:

```
fn modify1(r: &mut usize) {
    modify0(r);
}
```

Comment: I find it interesting that taking a reference of a reference still refers to the underlying data, i.e. somehow chains of references are flattened by Rust. I still don't have a good mental model of that.

Comment: Indeed. That is what confused me. I guess it's the price we have to pay to avoid writing `(*foo).bar()` all the time.